# How to a button preform function just when pressed

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I have problems by defined functions preforming by themselves, without me pressing the button.

I tried this:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

var1=StringVar()
e=Entry(root, width=20, textvariable=var1).grid(row=0,column=0)
a=var1.get()

def commm():
    name=str(var1.get())
    rootnew=Tk()
    rootnew.title(name)
    print(ime)

b=Button(root, text='makeWindow', command=commm()).grid(row=0, column=1)
```

but it creates two windows instead of one. One containing a Entry and Button and the other is empty.

Comment: It is always MUCh easier to use OOP while using tkinter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not execute `Tk` twice...

Create `Toplevel` widget instead.

But please also avoid:

```
from Tkinter import *
```

You should use `import Tkinter as tk`.